# Algorithm: Put y balls into x boxes where x <= y

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem that comes up when I was developing an app on Android. However, the problem is:

There are `x` boxes and `y` balls where `x <= y`, and I want to distribute the balls to put them inside the boxes **in order**. For example: 3 boxes; `box A`, `box B` and `box C` - and 5 balls; `ball 1`, `ball 2`, `ball 3`, `ball 4`, `ball 5`.

What I need is to put the first ball `ball 1` inside `box A`, and `ball 5` inside `box C` and the other balls are distributed between them all (does not matter if one box has more balls than the others). Here is a loop (missing an increment value) that simulates the problem:

```
int boxCount = 0; // first box is 0 and last box is x
int numOfBalls = y;
for(int i = 0; i < numOfBalls; i++, boxCount += ???)
{
    boxes.get(boxCount).add(balls.get(i));
}
```

What equation should I used instead of `???` to solve the problem?

---

**EDIT:**

Since `x <= y`, that means:

- None of the boxes should be empty.
- The difference between the boxes' balls number should not be more than 1.

---

**EDIT2**

By `in order`, I meant this:

```
A   B   C
---------
1   3   5
2   4
```

not

```
A   B   C
---------
1   2   3
4   5
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you want a uniform distribution of balls over boxes?

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek It does not matter if one box has balls more than the others.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Sorry I meant an even spaced distribution

Comment: @YetAnotherGeek What's `even spaced distribution`?

Comment: Do you have any other constraints?  For instance, would putting all but the last ball in the first box be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I mean like having 5 balls should be spread over the boxes as much as possible

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That would be not fair ;)

Comment: please clarify *exactly* how the balls should be distributed over the boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int flag;
int lastBallAdded = 0;
int k = numOfBalls/numOfBoxes;
int m = numOfBalls%numOfBoxes;

for(int i = 0; i < numOfBoxes; i++, lastBallAdded+=k+flag) {
    flag = i<m;

    for(int j=lastBallAdded;j<lastBallAdded + k + flag;j++) 
        boxes.get(i).add(balls.get(j));
}
```

This is the reasoning behind this solution:

by the definition of the problem, the algorithm should put `k= numOfBalls/numOfBoxes` balls in each box, except for the firsts `m = numOfBalls%numOfBoxes` boxes, where you should put `k+1` balls.

You can alternatively write it as

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    //add k+1 balls
}

for(;i<numOfBoxes; i++) {
    //add k balls
}
```

Comment: `flag = i<m;`, this is not compiling.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad try `flag = i<m ? 1 : 0;`. I'm a little bit rusty with java, I tried the code in C.

Comment: Well, it fails, when I tries to increase the number of boxes and number of balls.

Comment: `int numOfBalls = 10;` `int numOfBoxes = 4;` `A: [1, 2, 3]`
`B: [4, 5, 6]`
`C: [7, 8]`

Comment: oops, I forgot to print the last box `D: [9, 10]`, it works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

You can distribute `(int)n/k` balls in each of the first `k-1` boxes and the rest in the last box. This will be simplest to code.

With this: `boxCount += (i % (numOfBalls/numOfBoxes) == 0 && boxCount < numOfBoxes-1 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: This will put 3 balls into the first box.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: Of course it did, thanks. I missinterpeted what I wrote on the first line to the += statement... It is now doing what the description says it does. However, I see the question was editted and the OP is also looking for something more uniformly distributed

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me `A: [1]`
`B: [2]`
`C: [3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: As I stated in the comment, **it solves the initial question**, before the edit which asked "at most difference of 1". I am leaving it here because it might yet help someone else...

Answer (score 2):

```
int ball = 0;
for( int box = 0; box < x; ++box )
   while ( x * (ball+1) <= y * (box+1) )
      boxes.get(box).add(balls.get(ball++));
```

Loop invariant: The left `k` boxes contain fraction `k/x` of the balls (rounded).

Comment: This gives me: `A: [1]`
`B: [2, 3]`
`C: [4]`, it drops `5`

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Sorry, use `<=` instead of `<` in the while condition.  Edit applied.

Comment: Thanks mate, this is working very well now. However, I've accepted @Saphrosit's answer since he posted it before you :)

Comment: @Eng: Fine with me, he needs the points more than I do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, new try:

```
boxCount = ((i * nbrOfBoxes) / nbrOfBalls) + 1;
```

Note, the index of the balls are numbered from 0 to 4 (as in the for-loop). Remove the `+ 1` if yo would like the boxCount to be zero based.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3`

Comment: What is the index for box A to C? If it is `0..2` then remove the `+ 1` as suggested.